# Add condition in SQL Query about date

Tags: sql

i have this query which helps me show only the records that have an initiation day equal to today..

I have a yesterday variable..i Need to access like this:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME.time_added
FROM forma 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET WHERE forma.data_fillim = '$today'  ORDER BY forma.id DESC";
```

I need to modify it to something like:

```
$strSQL = "SELECT forma.*, SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET, SMS_MONTIME.MBYLLUR,SMS_MONTIME.time_added
FROM forma 
LEFT JOIN SMS_MONTIME ON forma.ID = SMS_MONTIME.IDTICKET WHERE forma.data_fillim = '$today' AND forma.data_fillim = '$yesterday'  ORDER BY forma.id DESC";
```

Thanks

Comment: this condition: `forma.data_fillim = '$today' AND forma.data_fillim = '$yesterday'` i think cannot return true if today and yesterday are properly set.

Comment: they both are YMD format..

Comment: how a date could be TODAY and YESTERDAY at the same time? Maybe you meant `forma.data_fillim = '$today' OR forma.data_fillim = '$yesterday'`

Comment: Yes..exactly..thanks, i solved this 1 min earlier :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shooting in the dark, but how about changing AND to OR?  If you already have $yesterday in the same format as $today but just that it is a different date, then you can use OR.  Alternatively you may use:

```
forma.data_fillim in ('$today', '$yesterday')
```

It also depends on what it is you REALLY want to do. If you are expecting a result for items inclusive of $yesterday and $today then you may use:

```
(forma.data_fillim >= '$yesterday') and (forma.data_fillim <= '$today')
```

If you are expecting a result for items that are either $yesterday or $today then you may use the previous snippet above (the one with the IN statement) OR use this

```
(forma.data_fillim = '$yesterday') or (forma.data_fillim = '$today')
```

You may use BETWEEN syntax which is true for MySQL and MSSQL.  I'm not sure about Oracle:

- MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between
- MSSQL: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922(v=sql.100).aspx

I hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

The date functions vary depending on the database you're using.

If it's Oracle you can use "date - 1" and it will subtract one day, on sqlserver and mysql I'm not sure about that "shortcut" but I'm sure they have a dateadd() or adddate() or something.

It will also vary if your database can interpret the string '$today' to a date in real time, so that you can use it in a date function

```
WHERE forma.data_fillim = '$today' OR forma.data_fillim = '$today' - 1
```

Comment: yesterday is supposed to be the yesterday date, so i don't need the -1 i guess...

I used this, i mean it's like i've set it above, but it didn't work..

Comment: I meant  '$today' - 1 but typed it wrong. Also, you should probably change AND to OR as pointed out because a date can't be two dates at the same time, or review your logic if that's not what you're trying to accomplish